# Java wait for next print

Tags: java, timer

I want the second print to happen after 2 seconds.

```
System.out.println("First print.");
//I want the code that makes the next System.out.println in 2 seconds.
System.out.println("This one comes after 2 seconds from the println.");
```

Comment: Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)

Comment: As the all-same-answer below tell you :)

Answer (score 5):

Just use [Thread#sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29):

```
System.out.println("First print.");
Thread.sleep(2000);//2000ms = 2s
System.out.println("This one comes after 2 seconds from the println.");
```

Note that `Thread.sleep` can throw an `InterruptedException`, so you will need a `throws` clause or a `try-catch`, like:

```
System.out.println("First print.");
try{
    Thread.sleep(2000);//2000ms = 2s
}catch(InterruptedException ex){
}
System.out.println("This one comes after 2 seconds from the println.");
```

or:

```
public void something() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("First print.");
    Thread.sleep(2000);//2000ms = 2s
    System.out.println("This one comes after 2 seconds from the println.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000); //2 secs
catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Thread#sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29):

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep

Note that you should use `try-catch` block around the call to `Thread.sleep()` because another Thread could interrupt `main()` while it's sleeping.  In this case, it's not necessary to catch it because there is only one Thread active, `main()`.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000)
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("main() Thread was interrupted while sleeping.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000); //2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your java code to sleep for 2 sec you can use the sleep function in Thread:

```
Thread.sleep(millisec);
```

The millisec argument is how many milliseconds you want to sleep f.ex:

```
1 sec = 1000 ms
2 sec = 2000 ms
and so on..
```

So your code will be something like this:

```
System.out.println("First print.");
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000); //2 secs
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("This one comes after 2 seconds from the println.");
```

(the try-catch is needed because sometimes it will throw a excpetion if the SecurityManager dont allow the thread to sleep but dont worry, thats will never happen..)
-Max